# Python remove line if value X

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframe A and B
I want to remove line with if the are not present in second database

```
A :
   A    B      C
1 ex1  ex12  ex13
2 ex11 ex22  ex23
3 ex31 ex32  ex33
4 ex41 ex42  ex43
5 ex51 ex52  ex53
...

B:

   A
1 ex22
2 ex42
3 ex52
...
```

So I need to get solution like

```
A' =
   A    B      C
1 ex11 ex22  ex23
2 ex41 ex42  ex43
3 ex51 ex52  ex53
...
```

Comment: This does not seem related to MySQL, so I removed that tag.

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of columns A and C.

Comment: It is good that you have shown a source dataset and an expected output. However your question is not clear. Show us what you have tried and explain your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common semi-join

```
A <- data.table::fread("A    B      C
ex1  ex12  ex13
ex11 ex22  ex23
ex31 ex32  ex33
ex41 ex42  ex43
ex51 ex52  ex53")

B <- data.table::fread(

"B
ex22
ex42
ex52")

library(tidyverse)

A %>% 
  dplyr::semi_join(B)

Joining, by = "B"
     A    B    C
1 ex11 ex22 ex23
2 ex41 ex42 ex43
3 ex51 ex52 ex53
```

Comment: @Licht Does this solve your problem, if so please consider checking as the correct answer and upvoting